# Django .order_by() related field returns too many items

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to return a list of users that have recently made a post, but the order_by method makes it return too many items.

there is only 2 accounts total, but when I call

```
test = Account.objects.all().order_by('-posts__timestamp')
[print(i) for i in test]
```

it will return the author of every post instance, and its duplicates. Not just the two account instances.

```
test@test.example
test@test.example
test@test.example
test@test.example
foo@bar.example
```

Any help?

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...

class Posts(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account',on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name="posts")
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = ...
    content = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally normal. You should understand how is the SQL query generated.
Yours should look something like that:

```sql
select *
from accounts
  left join post on post.account_id = account.id
order by post.timestamp
```

You are effectively selecting every post with its related users. It is normal that you have some duplicated users.

What you could do is ensure that your are selecting distinct users: `Account.objects.order_by('-posts__timestamp').distinct('pk')`

What I would do is *cache* this information in the account (directly on the acount model or in another model that has a 1-to-1 relashionship with your users.
Adding a `last_post_date` to your Account model would allow you to have a less heavy request.

Updating the `Account.last_post_date` every time a `Post` is created can be a little tedious, but you can abstract this by using [django models signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save).

Comment: Perfect! `Distinct` wont work because i'm using MySQL. Signals work great!